# Origin of the phrase "Hyuga are Konoha's strongest"

Tags: naruto

I have seen it being used in the episodes where Konoha was invaded by Orochimaru when Hinata's father engages the enemy stating that. Now I see that being used in the current ninja war when Neji remarks to Naruto about that?

Is there any basis for the origin of this phrase in the manga or anime anywhere regarding the strength of Hyuga clan?

Comment: Or they are just boasting, like 'we are the best'! A good tactic to impress your opponent! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was seen first in the Chūnin exam, when Kakashi said this during the battle between Hinata and Neji. That path was followed in the fight between Naruto and Neji.

The reason is, that the members of the Hyūga can manipulate the chakra of their enemies and thus can win against most ninjas. And since the massacre of the Uchiha-clan, who could be better than the Hyūgas?

Comment: any group of long range fighters like shikamaru's clan for instance.

Comment: naruto bested him.. :P